# Pointer array operations in Fortran - Lower bound error

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, fortran90

I want to store a 3D array pointer into a 4D array pointer but I am having some trouble. For example:

```
real,pointer :: p(:,:,:,:) => null()
integer :: ndims,d

ndims = 3
do d=1,ndims
  p(d,:,:,:) => function
end do
```

Where `function` is a function pointer which returns a pointer such as `p(:,:,:)` and this works fine. The error I am getting is that `Lower bound has to be present` at this line: `p(d,:,:,:) => function`, but I have performed this sort of operations before (not with pointers) and it worked okay. What am I missing here?

Comment: You currently have a single rank four pointer.  At any one time, you can *point* that single rank four pointer at a single target array.  Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/8901228/1234550 might help.

Comment: Yes, but I want to point at at different rank 3 arrays and store this in the rank 4 pointer, where the extra rank account for these different arrays. Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this comes from a common misunderstanding of what

```
real,pointer :: p(:,:,:,:) => null()
```

is actually doing in fortran.

It is not a 4D array of pointers but a pointer 'p' to a 4D array.

What you can do is play a little trick and create a struct with a pointer inside:

```
type pointer4D
   real, pointer :: p
end type pointer4D
type(pointer4D), dimension(:) :: arr
```

Your code would thus become:

```
do d=1,ndims
  arr(d)%p => function
end do
```

Assuming 'function' is some sort of 3D object, you can access the element I,j,k of the dimension N by doing

```
arr(N)%p(I,j,k)
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Yeap, I was basically confused by the definition of `p`.  This is different as in c++ right?

Comment: @bfg yes. In C++, if I'm not mistaken, you can define an array of pointers as p[ndim]. This is not possible in Fortran.