How to determine if a variable with a class has been allocated to an extended type if the variable is in an array?
If we have a variable CLASS(BaseType), ALLOCATABLE :: foo, Type1 and Type2 which extends BaseType, and then we ALLOCATE(Type1::foo), I can use ALLOCATED(foo) to check if foo has been allocated to a derived type.
However, a problem arises when I try to have an array of CLASS(BaseType), ALLOCATABLE :: foo(:). Then this example code below gives a compilation error:
MODULE test_mod

TYPE BaseType
ENDTYPE BaseType

TYPE, EXTENDS(BaseType) :: Type1
ENDTYPE Type1 

TYPE, EXTENDS(BaseType) :: Type2
ENDTYPE Type2

CLASS(BaseType), ALLOCATABLE :: foo(:)

END MODULE test_mod

PROGRAM TEST
USE test_mod

ALLOCATE(foo(2))
ALLOCATE(Type1::foo(1))

IF (ALLOCATED(foo(1))) PRINT*, 'allocated foo ',1
IF (ALLOCATED(foo(2))) PRINT*, 'allocated foo ',2

END PROGRAM TEST

This gives the error:
TEST.f90:22:14:

   22 | IF (ALLOCATED(foo(1))) PRINT*, 'allocated foo',1
      |              1
Error: ‘array’ argument of ‘allocated’ intrinsic at (1) must be ALLOCATABLE
TEST.f90:23:14:

   23 | IF (ALLOCATED(foo(2))) PRINT*, 'allocated foo',2
      |              1
Error: ‘array’ argument of ‘allocated’ intrinsic at (1) must be ALLOCATABLE

The declaration of foo(:) shows that it is clearly ALLOCATABLE, but I don't know how to declare it such that each element is also ALLOCATABLE. If this is not the problem, how do I check if an element within an array has been declared as a derived type of BaseType?

foo may well be allocatable, but foo(1) isn't, and never can be.

But what do you think allocate(foo(2)) is doing? If you think it's allocating foo(2) as an element to something, it isn't: it's allocating the whole array foo to be of size 2.

In a hurry but you want something similar to the array of pointers trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900336/arrays-of-pointers

The linked question is about how to do what you want to do, rather than what is wrong with your current code. If you need to understand more about why your attempt doesn't work, we can explain.
